# Combine many similar regex in one in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am not familiar with Regex. Actually, I've just started with it. I have three different patterns

```
pattern = re.compile(r'SETUP...\d+')
pattern = re.compile(r'PRO...\d+')
pattern = re.compile(r'INSTALL...\d+')
```

Some of my strings are `SETUP1234, SETUP = 1234, SETUP 1234, SETUP-1234` etc. The same with the others. So, I decide that 3 characters between the prefix and the numbers is a reasonable way to use it. But my problem now is, can I combine the three of them in one Regex instead of calling three different `findall`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `|` like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(SETUP|PRO|INSTALL)...\d+')
```

it means that any of `SETUP`, `PRO` or `INSTALL`.

Also, the pattern can be improved a little, like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(SETUP|PRO|INSTALL).{1,3}\d+')
```

This allows 1 to 3 characters to be used in between the words and the numbers.

As [Tim suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855958/combine-many-similar-regex-in-one-in-python/22855982#comment34868445_22855982), you can use [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/1903116) like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:SETUP|PRO|INSTALL).{1,3}\d+')
print pattern.findall("SETUP 1234")
# ['SETUP 1234']
print pattern.findall("PRO 1234")
# ['PRO 1234']
print pattern.findall("INSTALL 1234")
# ['INSTALL 1234']
```

Comment: If you want the non-capturing version, you can make it `(?:SETUP|PRO|INSTALL)...\d+`

Comment: This return only the first part of the pattern (eg SETUP)

Comment: @Sfinos Please check the updated answer, non-capturing version will give the entire string.